# Exporting a custom module from one instance to another

Tags: 7, views

I am new to Drupal. Currently I am using Drupal 7.4.

Hhow to export a custom module from one instance to another instance?

Note: copy the module to the new site didn't work.

Comment: Just copy the module into the new site, and enable. Nothing more to it

Comment: Tired that but it didnt work out.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you need to do:

- Before you try anything, make sure you have a backup of everything
- Copy the module directory into the correct directory in the other Drupal site
- Enable the custom module

  - from the `/admin/modules` page
  - from the command-line using the `drush en MODULE` command
- If the module requires any configuration, then you will have to do the configuration on the second website as well

  - If you have used the `features` module, it can be helpful in transferring module configuration